# Apex Sharing of Case to All Internal Users

Tags: apex, apex-managed-sharing

I am having an issue whereby I have created an Apex method to create a CaseShare record for a particular case.

The manual share record provides Read access to the standard group "All Internal Users: based on the Record Type of the case. The sharing record gets created fine and is visible when I access the "Sharing" button on the record through Salesforce Classic. However the problem arises when I try to login with any other user to view this newly shared case in that the case does not appear.

In order to check that it was not a permissions related issue I created a sharing rule to share any records created with the particular record type with the group All Internal Users and disabled my Apex Sharing rule and this worked just fine the case was created by Apex and the rule shared it out. I also tried to create the Apex sharing rule to share to a specific user and this also worked so cannot figure out why Apex sharing to 'All Internal Users' is not working.

Here is how the Share record is being created

```
                Group AllInternalUsers = [Select Id from Group where DeveloperName='AllInternalUsers'];

                Id AllInternalUsersId = AllInternalUsers.Id


                CaseShare cseShr = new CaseShare();

                cseShr.CaseId = newCase.Id;
                cseShr.UserOrGroupId = AllInternalUsersId;
                cseShr.CaseAccessLevel  = 'Read';

                insert cseShr;
```

Is there something that I am missing when sharing case records to groups or anyone run into this issue before? The issue also seems to occur when I create a manual sharing record via the "Sharing" button in Classic to share to All Internal Users.

Thanks in Advance

Comment: It is unusual. I could not find too much documentation on the standard group AllInternalUsers. I can't even find a list of the users in the group when I query for them. `Select Id, (Select Id, UserOrGroupId FROM GroupMembers) FROM Group`.
Unfortunately I can't explain why it doesnt work, but your logic seems correct. I would try using a 'custom' public group and see if this works. If it does, you can narrow down the cause of this to the AllInternalUsers group.

Comment: You can always open a case with Salesforce, but from experience, you will wait a couple weeks just for them to tell you what you already knew

Comment: I tried the above on my dev org and it worked just fine. May be try one more time and see if for some reason it is taking a few seconds for the sharing to take effect on your org?

Comment: @Z33dawg a custom group with All Internal Users added to it did the trick however it is not the most elegant solution but is working for now.

Comment: @Aayush K I also tried this in a Dev Org and it was working for me there. What I am finding the most strange about it is even if I create the manual share record via the sharing button in Classic its still not visible